# objective c moving snake tail

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a snake game with two tails (player vs. device). After I built the grid, I started working on moving the tail towards right direction. The problem that I face is the tail is not moving.

The following code is creating an image of arrow (right arrow) so that a user can click this arrow to move to the right:

```
self.arrowRight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(90, 39, 27, 27)];
        [_arrowRight setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-arrow.png"]];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightTap)];
        [_arrowRight setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [_arrowRight addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
        [_viewB addSubview:_arrowRight];

-(void)rightTap{
    [self moveRight];
}
```

The following code creates a subview of the tail on the grid where:

x is defined as the axis that will be changed every time it moves to the right

viewA1 is the subview of the tail and ViewA is the view of the grid

```
_x=39;
    int l;
    UIView *viewA1;
    for (l=0; l<6; l++) {
        viewA1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_x,48,11,11)];
        viewA1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [_viewA addSubview:viewA1];
        _x += 12;
    }
```

The following code is the moveRight method:

```
-(IBAction)moveRight {

    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(moveRight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"movingright" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    _x = 39;
    _vPlayer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_x,48,11,11)];
    _vPlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _x += 12;
    [_viewA addSubview:_vPlayer];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Can someone help me solving this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you keep creating tails and never removing them. Keep track of the view(s) that make up the tail and either update their frames or remove them from their superview.

Note that each time round the `for` loop that you show you create a new `viewA1` and add it to the others. They will not be released until their superview is as the superview maintains a strong reference to it's subviews.

Answer (score 0):

`_x` is a value, and `CGRect` is a struct. They get copied on assign. So such code won't work:

```
_x = 39;
_vPlayer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_x,48,11,11)];
_x += 12;
```

You need to create completely new frame to move a view:

```
_vPlayer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_x,48,11,11)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:^{ //just a more common way to animate views then beginAnimations/commitAnimations
    CGRect old = _vPlayer.frame;
    _vPlayer.frame = CGRectOffset(old, 12, 0);
    //OR using center property: _vPlayer.center = CGPointMake(_vPlayer.center.x + 12, _vPlayer.center.y)
}];
```

(Also I'm not sure you need to create new view every time button pressed, if you are not trying to make tail grow with every step. In this case you should just remove `_x = 39` line and create views in new locations without reseting x coord.)

I'm hoping it will help.